# Dynamically generate data based notifications platform

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, notifications, bigdata, geospatial

In our project we have a requirement to create dynamic notifications that "pop" in our site when a relevant rule applies.
We are based on oracle exadata as our main database.

This feature is suppose to allow the users to create dynamic rules that will be occasionally checked.
These rules may check specific fields in certain types, and may also check these fields relatively to other types field's data.
For example, if our program has a table of cars, with a location column, and another table of streets, with location column (no direct relation between those two tables), we might need to notify the users if a car is in a certain street.

Is there a good platform that can help us calculate the kind of "rules" that we want to check?

We started looking at elasticsearch and neo4j (we have a specific module that involves a graph-like relations..), but we aren't sure that they would be the right solution.

Any idea would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j could help you to express your rules, but it sounds as if your disconnected data is rather queried by SQL style joins?

So if you want to express and manage your rules in predicates in the graph you can do that easily and then get a list of applicable rules to trigger queries in other databases.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. but our problem is that we are not sure which other databases should run the triggered queries.